# Multiple CSS Backgrounds set to cover with 50% 100% size (and fixed!)

Tags: html, css, background

- Fixed background single image? **✔**
- Fixed background, single image, scaled and centered? **✔**
- Two backgrounds, 50% on each side? **✔**
- Three backgrounds, 33% each, cover style scaling, while also being 100% height? **✘**

I need *three* background images, each taking up 33% of the screen laid out like so:

```
11111|22222|33333
11111|22222|33333
11111|22222|33333
11111|22222|33333
11111|22222|33333
```

This background needs to be fixed because other stuff is sliding on top of it. I've managed to *kinda* get this working with two background images with the following:

```
.multiple-background {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("img1.jpg"), url("img2.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
    background-clip: border-box, border-box;
    background-origin: padding-box, padding-box;
    background-size: 50% 100%;
    background-position: left top, right top;
}
```

Unfortunately this stretches the background images. I need something that will allow me to fix the amount of horizontal space an image takes up (33%) while also doing 100% width and cover style scaling.

Switching in something like `background-size: 50% auto;` does the scaling correctly but now it doesn't cover the full background.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with `background-size`. `contain`, `cover` and `auto` *all* scale an image based on its intrinsic ratio only.

Comment: Side note, if a certain background property has the same value for all backgrounds, you can specify it just once and it'll be propagated to the rest of the backgrounds. That means `background-attachment: fixed` is equivalent to `background-attachment: fixed, fixed` for example, and likewise for `background-clip`, `background-origin` and `background-repeat`.

Comment: @BoltClock I copied that from FF's inspector so that's the expanded CSS. Good tip though!

Comment: @BoltClock If I can't do it with one element, what's the best element structure to do it with multiple?

Comment: Why can't you combine the 3 images into one in a photo editor and scale it to meet your needs? Then just lay the content out over it as you need it. Also, if you put together a fiddle, it might be easier to help you find a solution.

Comment: @innerurge1: The background has to scale according to the content. That's not something an image editor can do unless the image was created in a vector format. (And even then it's still up to the CSS to figure out how to scale the image as intended, hence the question.)

Comment: @innerurge1 Because they need to scale with the background (images will scale with the browser).

Answer (score 0):

use differenet elements for each background and set **position absolute and z-index value** for ordering